# Error in installing lib64stdc++6 package

Tags: software-installation, libraries

I was following the instructions to run AVD emulator from this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928340/how-to-start-an-android-emulator-in-ubuntu-16-04).
On running `sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386`, I'm getting this error:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
lib64stdc++6:i386 : Depends: lib64gcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libc6-amd64:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to resolve this?

I have tried `sudo apt-get update`. Didn't help.

On installing first one (lib64gcc1:i386), unmet dependency on second one(libc6-amd64:i386) is coming.

On installing second one(libc6-amd64:i386), getting this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-amd64:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.14) but 2.24-9ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
```

And libc6:i386 is already installed. On running `dpkg -L libc6:i386`, I'm getting this:

```
/.
/etc
/etc/ld.so.conf.d
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf
/lib
/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSegFault.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libanl-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcidn-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_hesiod-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nisplus-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcprofile.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.24.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db-1.0.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.24.so
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/audit
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/audit/sotruss-lib.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ANSI_X3.110.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ARMSCII-8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ASMO_449.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/BIG5.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/BIG5HKSCS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/BRF.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP10007.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1125.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1250.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1251.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1252.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1253.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1254.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1255.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1256.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1257.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP1258.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP737.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP770.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP771.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP772.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP773.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP774.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP775.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CP932.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CSN_369103.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/CWI.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/DEC-MCS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-AT-DE-A.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-AT-DE.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-CA-FR.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-DK-NO-A.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-DK-NO.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-ES-A.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-ES-S.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-ES.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-FI-SE-A.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-FI-SE.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-FR.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-IS-FRISS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-IT.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-PT.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-UK.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EBCDIC-US.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ECMA-CYRILLIC.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EUC-CN.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EUC-JISX0213.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EUC-JP-MS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EUC-JP.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EUC-KR.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/EUC-TW.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GB18030.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GBBIG5.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GBGBK.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GBK.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GEORGIAN-ACADEMY.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GEORGIAN-PS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GOST_19768-74.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GREEK-CCITT.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GREEK7-OLD.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/GREEK7.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/HP-GREEK8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/HP-ROMAN8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/HP-ROMAN9.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/HP-THAI8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/HP-TURKISH8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM037.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM038.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1004.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1008.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1008_420.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1025.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1026.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1046.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1047.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1097.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1112.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1122.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1123.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1124.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1129.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1130.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1132.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1133.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1137.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1140.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1141.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1142.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1143.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1144.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1145.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1146.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1147.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1148.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1149.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1153.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1154.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1155.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1156.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1157.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1158.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1160.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1161.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1162.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1163.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1164.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1166.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1167.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM12712.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1364.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1371.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1388.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1390.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM1399.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM16804.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM256.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM273.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM274.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM275.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM277.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM278.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM280.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM281.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM284.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM285.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM290.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM297.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM420.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM423.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM424.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM437.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM4517.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM4899.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM4909.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM4971.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM500.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM5347.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM803.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM850.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM851.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM852.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM855.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM856.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM857.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM860.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM861.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM862.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM863.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM864.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM865.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM866.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM866NAV.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM868.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM869.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM870.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM871.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM874.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM875.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM880.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM891.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM901.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM902.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM903.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM9030.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM904.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM905.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM9066.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM918.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM921.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM922.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM930.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM932.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM933.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM935.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM937.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM939.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM943.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM9448.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/IEC_P27-1.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/INIS-8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/INIS-CYRILLIC.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/INIS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISIRI-3342.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO-2022-CN-EXT.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO-2022-CN.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO-2022-JP-3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO-2022-JP.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO-2022-KR.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO-IR-197.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO-IR-209.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO646.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-10.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-11.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-13.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-14.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-15.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-16.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-2.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-3.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-4.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-5.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-6.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-7.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-9.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-9E.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_10367-BOX.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_11548-1.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_2033.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_5427-EXT.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_5427.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_5428.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_6937-2.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO_6937.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/JOHAB.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/KOI-8.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/KOI8-R.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/KOI8-RU.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/KOI8-T.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/KOI8-U.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/LATIN-GREEK-1.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/LATIN-GREEK.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/MAC-CENTRALEUROPE.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/MAC-IS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/MAC-SAMI.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/MAC-UK.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/MACINTOSH.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/MIK.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/NATS-DANO.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/NATS-SEFI.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/PT154.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/RK1048.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/SAMI-WS2.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/SHIFT_JISX0213.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/SJIS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/T.61.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/TCVN5712-1.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/TIS-620.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/TSCII.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/UHC.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/UNICODE.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-16.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-32.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-7.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/VISCII.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/libCNS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/libGB.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/libISOIR165.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/libJIS.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/libJISX0213.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/libKSC.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libc6
/usr/share/doc/libc6/BUGS
/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libc6/README.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libc6/README.hesiod.gz
/usr/share/doc/libc6/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libc6/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libc6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libanl.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcidn.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_hesiod.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nisplus.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

What should i do?

Comment: @user535733 I successfully installed gradle just before that. Everything else is working fine. It's just this `lib64stdc++6` that's giving this type of error on installation.

Comment: Please link to the instructions you followed, and edit your question include the relevant section of /var/log/apt/term.log

Comment: @user535733 added the link of the answer i was following in the question. Also here it is(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928340/how-to-start-an-android-emulator-in-ubuntu-16-04).
And there's nothing in the log about this. Log starts after it asks for disk permission usage right?  I can't find anything in log related to above commands I executed.

Comment: Check prior days logs, too.

Comment: Hmmm. Is 32-bit intentional?

Comment: @user535733 Nothing in log. By the way i don't know much about log, that's why asking, `How can previous days logs be even related to commands I ran just now?`
And no i didn't know it's 32-bit (until now). Totally unintentional.

Comment: I was guessing on time - we didn't know it was today. If you want 64-bit then try again, omit the `:i386`

Comment: @user535733 already tried, same result.
Should I try to manually install it(by downloading zip file and all)?
If yes, then from where?

Comment: Do nothing until a guru with better ideas comes along. Tinkering often makes the problem worse.

Comment: Okay!! By the way thanks for your time @user535733

Answer (score 0):

I hope i'm not late but this method fixed this problem for me ,

first install libc6-amd64:i386 by

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-amd64:i386
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install lib64gcc1:i386
```

and finally

```
sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6
             or
apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
```

Now change directory to Android_Path/Sdk/tools/lib64

```
mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak 

ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++
```

thats it . now try to run your emulator